# Can I compare the value of options in my select box to the time values in my database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm making a room reservation system in PHP and mySQL.

```
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="from" class="fromLabel">From</label>
                                    <select required name="from" id="from" class="form-select form-select-lg">
                                        <option selected disabled value="">Pick a time</option>
                                        <option value="08:00:00">8 a.m.</option>
                                        <option value="09:00:00">9 a.m.</option>
                                        <option value="10:00:00">10 a.m.</option>
                                        <option value="11:00:00">11 a.m.</option>
                                        <option value="12:00:00">12 p.m.</option>
                                        <option value="13:00:00">1 p.m.</option>
                                        <option value="14:00:00">2 p.m.</option>
                                        <option value="15:00:00">3 p.m.</option>
                                        <option value="16:00:00">4 p.m.</option>
                                        <option value="17:00:00">5 p.m.</option>
                                        <option value="18:00:00">6 p.m.</option>
                                        <option value="19:00:00">7 p.m.</option>
                                        <option value="20:00:00">8 p.m.</option>
                                        <option value="21:00:00">9 p.m.</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="to" class="toLabel">To</label>
                                    <select required name="to" id="to" class="form-select form-select-lg">
                                        <option selected disabled value="">Pick a time</option>
                                        <option value="09:00:00">9 a.m.</option>
                                        <option value="10:00:00">10 a.m.</option>
                                        <option value="11:00:00">11 a.m.</option>
                                        <option value="12:00:00">12 p.m.</option>
                                        <option value="13:00:00">1 p.m.</option>
                                        <option value="14:00:00">2 p.m.</option>
                                        <option value="15:00:00">3 p.m.</option>
                                        <option value="16:00:00">4 p.m.</option>
                                        <option value="17:00:00">5 p.m.</option>
                                        <option value="18:00:00">6 p.m.</option>
                                        <option value="19:00:00">7 p.m.</option>
                                        <option value="20:00:00">8 p.m.</option>
                                        <option value="21:00:00">9 p.m.</option>
                                        <option value="22:00:00">10 p.m.</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
```

This is the HTML code for my select box. In my database, I have a field called start and end that's supposed to supposed to store the start and end time of booking for a room. I was wondering if there is a way to compare the values of the options with the database and disable the times that are already booked

Comment: Yes there would definitely be a way to do that, probably using SQL to get the booked times. What have you researched / tried so far? What are you stuck on specfically? Questions which elicit a yes/no style answer are not a good fit for Stackoverflow, instead focus on a particular issue within your attempt to solve it. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your static web page to a dynamic one using PHP and a MySQL database.

At first, I created a database called **test** with a single table **booking** and the fields **id (int)**, **arrival (datetime)** and **departure (datetime)**.

I added some values in it :

[image]

Then, you will need to connect to your database :

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
```

Once you are successfully connected, you need a SELECT statement to get arrivals and departures from database :

```
$sql = "SELECT arrival, departure FROM booking";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Finally, you have to fetch datas and to add all arrivals in an array (then you should do the same for departures but I will show you for arrivals as you only need to copy / paste).

```
$opening_hour = 8;
$closure_hour = 21;

$arrivals = [];

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  
    $arrival_hour = date_parse($row["arrival"])['hour'];
  
    $arrivals[] = $arrival_hour;
  
  }
} 

$conn->close();
```

As you loop through the arrivals array, you need to set select's options as disabled if you can find them out into the array.

```
    <label for="from">Arrival time :</label>
    <select required name="from" id="from" class="form-select form-select-lg">

        <option selected disabled value="">Pick a time</option>

        <?php 

        for ($hour = $opening_hour; $hour <= $closure_hour; $hour++) {

            if(in_array($hour, $arrivals)) {

                echo "<option disabled value='" . $hour . "'>" . $hour . "</option>";

            } else {

                echo "<option value='" . $hour . "'>" . $hour . "</option>";
            }


        }

        ?>

    </select>
```

Here is the final result :

[image]